# Problems working out the re.compile mask/cypher

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-re

I have working code using re.compile that searches for a given key and extracts specified bytes from that line.

```
Working cypher
S011=re.compile(r"S0\w*\W*11\b")

Searches for 'S0' at the start and '11' further in (the intervening alphanumeric changes with each file)
S012PA041       11   1001650953.34N  72627.05E 426930.97227906.7 285.3227033224
```

I am trying to use the same method for a different input file but I can't work out the correct mask/cypher. There are several lines starting 'P1' so that in not exclusive enough; the 'P1....,V0' is the exclusive key. Again the numbers between the keys change with each event and file.

```
P1,0,01169-72-063,,1001,,1,2020:07:31:12:48:01.7,1,V01,2,,436389.57,7196330.69,,64.88354429,7.65691702,,64.88327349,7.65520631,,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,,248.04
```

I have tried these but with no success:

```
V0=re.compile(r"^P1\w*\W*V0")
V0=re.compile(r"^P1\w*\W*V0\w*\W*")
V0=re.compile(r"^P1\w*V0\w*")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running more combinations than an safe-cracker on Red Bull, I've finally got the right sequence for the regex.

Line to be identified using 'P1' and further in 'V01' as search keys

```
P1,0,01169-72-063,,1001,,1,2020:07:31:12:48:01.7,1,V01,2,,436389.57,7196330.69,,64.88354429,7.65691702,,64.88327349,7.65520631,,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,,248.04
```

re.compile code to identify it.

```
 V0=re.compile(r"^P1\s*,*:*\S*V01\s*,*:*\S*\b")
```